# Sulu2.2 Media Upload page turns blank after loading

Tags: sulu

Using Chromium, Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu I get the following error in the Console when trying to open the Admin Media Upload pages:

```
Error: The list field transformer with the key "icon" is not defined. You probably forgot to add it to the registry using the "add" method.
    at e.value (listFieldTransformerRegistry.js:29)
    at AbstractTableAdapter.js:39
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at i.value (AbstractTableAdapter.js:38)
    at TableAdapter.js:61
    at mobx.module.js:3452
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at t.<anonymous> (mobx.module.js:3451)
    at i.value (TableAdapter.js:52)
    at i.value (TableAdapter.js:95)
eu @ react-dom.production.min.js:209
```

and after shortly showing the folders I get a blank white page and cannot proceed (uploading images).

Hosted build with composer version `"sulu/sulu: "~2.2"`

Answer (score 1):

The error sounds like you did upgrade Sulu to a newer version but did not upgrade the javascript build. Have a look at sulu upgrade guide:

https://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/upgrades/upgrade-2.x.html

The command mention there need to be run when you update sulu:

```
bin/console sulu:admin:update-build
```